# Regex for finding message identifiers

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Please a regex expert help me out I totally done for with this.

Here is an example from the text:

```
BO_ 2617247491 Msg_06: 8 DataloggerConfiguration
 SG_ DL_error_active_3 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_active_2 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_active_1 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_active_0 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_5 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_4 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_3 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_2 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_1 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_0 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX

BO_ 2617248003 Msg_08: 8 DataloggerConfiguration
 SG_ DL_gl_err_rea : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_gl_err_rea_hi : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX

BO_ 617247747 Msg_07: 8 DataloggerConfiguration
 SG_ DL_error_code_11 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_10 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_6 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_di_nr_of_active_entries : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_9 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_8 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
 SG_ DL_error_code_7 : 11|8@1+ (1,0) [0|1111] "[-]" Vector__XXX
```

I am trying to find those meassage identifiers (10 digit nums. after the BO_), which are followed by in it anywhere a DL_error_code.

As far as I got is this regex:

```cs
(?<!VAL_\s)\d{10}(?=.*\n*.*DL_error_code)
```

Comment: Any reason your regex *didn't* include the text `BO_`? I would think this would be fairly simply: `"BO_\s+(?<id>\d+)\s+"`

Comment: or simply... 
^BO_ (\d{10})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be using a capture group.

```
^BO_ (\d{10}).*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*BO_|.*?DL_error_code).*)*\r?\n.*?DL_error_code
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of the string
- `BO_`  Match literally
- `(\d{10})` Capture 10 digits in **group 1**
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!\s*BO_|.*?DL_error_code).*` Match the whole line if it does not start with `BO_` or contains DL_error_code
- `)*` Close group and optionally repeat
- `\r?\n.*?DL_error_code` Match the line that contains DL_error_code

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SFeNGE/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/1yrrBE)

Note that the second item has 9 digits `617247747`

If you want to match [all the digits](https://regex101.com/r/qBt0Um/1), you might also use `\d+` instead of `\d{10}` which would match 1 or more digits.

```
string pattern = @"^BO_ (\d{10}).*(?:\r?\n(?!\s*BO_|.*?DL_error_code).*)*\r?\n.*?DL_error_code";
string input = @"...";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Output

```
2617247491
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been parsing text files for over 40 years.  String methods should be used when they can be used and regex when string method do not work.  Regex is not always the best answer.  See my code below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);

            string line = "";
            List<BO> bos = new List<BO>();
            BO bo = null;
            string[] splitLine = null;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (line.StartsWith("BO"))
                    {
                        bo = new BO();
                        bos.Add(bo);
                        splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).ToArray();
                        bo.number = splitLine[1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (line.Contains("DL_error_code"))
                        {
                            splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }).ToArray();
                            if (bo.de_error_codes == null) bo.de_error_codes = new List<string>();
                            bo.de_error_codes.Add(splitLine[1].Trim());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public class BO
    {
        public string number { get; set; }
        public List<string> de_error_codes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out too. It is an interesting solution.